# How to upload image with json which is serialized from model using retrofit android

Tags: android, json, image, retrofit

Please i need help i need to send this model with image using retrofit but it's not working it's working using postman as in the screenshot so what can i do to solve this issue

```
public class Package implements Comparable<Package>, Parcelable {
@SerializedName("id")
public String ID;
@SerializedName("name")
public String title;
@SerializedName("description")
public String description;
@SerializedName("value")}
```

this model i need to add image on the same model to send using retrofit like this

```
public interface ApiInterface {
@Multipart
@Headers("Content-Type: multipart/form-data")
@POST("packages/add")
Single<Result<AddPackageResponseModel>> addPackage(@Part("image") RequestBody image,
                                                   @Part("json")  RequestBody addPackageModel,
                                                   @Query("token") String token);}
```

this is how i created the request body

```
 File imageFile = ImageHelper.convertBitmapToFile(addPackageModel.getImage(), "image", context);
    RequestBody packageImageFileRequestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), imageFile);
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
    String addPackageModelJSON = gson.toJson(addPackageModel);

    RequestBody addPackageJSONRequestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), addPackageModelJSON);

    compositeDisposable.add(addPackageInteractor.addPackage(packageImageFileRequestBody,
            addPackageJSONRequestBody, token)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Consumer<Result<AddPackageResponseModel>>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(@NonNull Result<AddPackageResponseModel> responseResult) throws Exception {
                        if (responseResult.response().body() != null) {
                            addPackageView.addPackageSuccess();
                        }
                    }
            }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(@NonNull Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                }
            }));
```

this is postman with backend and it's working fine when using postman

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I  did something like what you are doing in my project which was my first android project.

I had an image and I tried to send it to server alongside my json as multipart and this was what I did:

First I created a file like:

```
File img = new File(avatar);
```

which avatar is an address to a file.

Then I created a `RequestBody` object like:

```
RequestBody requestFile= RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), img);
MultipartBody.Part body =null;
if(avatar!="")
   body =  MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("avatar", img.getName(), requestFile);
```

Then with my Retrofit object called `obj` I did this:

```
obj.registerNewUser(RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),user.getUserName())
                    ,RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),user.getFullName())
                    ,body,RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),user.getPassword())).enqueue(new Callback<Data.User>() {...
//handle the response with onResponse and onFailure functions
}
```

And my `registerNewUser` was like this:

```
@Multipart
    @POST("user/register/")
    Call<Data.User> registerNewUser(@Part("username") RequestBody username, @Part("fullname") RequestBody fullname, @Part MultipartBody.Part avatar, @Part("password") RequestBody password);
```

I hope my answer was helpful for you.

Comment: thanks very much for your reply, it's helpful but i need something more advanced i have another object in my model like dimension (width - height - length) so should i get every field in my model and make like what you did there is nothing more easier than this where i can send the model and retrofit make this effort? thanks in advance